# How many electrons in a ferromagnetic material, per atom, have their spins pointing in the same direction?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, magnetic-moment

Is there a list or chart somewhere that states, approximately, how many outer electrons per atom in a particular ferromagnetic material are aligned?

Are there, say, five electrons in an FeO2 magnet's atom (assuming it is as highly magnetized as possible) all pointing 'up' (or, at the other end, 'down')?

And, for Ne2Fe14B, perhaps eight electrons per neodymium magnet are aligned?

I thought it would be easy to find this information, but so far, no luck.....